# Swift Protocol Arrays Adding vs. Instantiating

Tags: swift

In swift 3.0 Xcode beta 3, I defined a fairly simple protocol and two structs that implement it, if I initialize the array when creating the objects, it works, but if I try to add elements I get an error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[H]' to expected argument type 'inout _'

Shouldn't this work?

```
protocol H {
    var v : Int { get set }
    func hello()
}

struct J : H {
    var v : Int
    func hello() {
        print("j")
    }
}

struct K : H {
    var v : Int
    func hello() {
        print("k")
    }
}

let ag:[H] =  [K(v:3), J(v:4)] // works
ag[0].hello()
ag[1].hello()

var af:[H] =  []
af += [K(v:3)] // does not work
af += [J(v:4)] // does not work
af[0].hello()
af[1].hello()
```

Comment: `var af:[H] =  []` is better written as: `var af = [H]()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a type issue. You need the things you add to `af` to be the same type as `af`, namely `[H]`:

```
var af:[H] = []
let arr1:[H] = [K(v:3)]
let arr2:[H] = [J(v:4)]
af += arr1
af += arr2
```

Comment: Thanks that solves it but it seems unnatural: This also works var af:[H] =  []
let w : H = K(v:3)
let x : H = J(v:3)
af += [w]
af += [x]
af[0].hello()
af[1].hello()

Comment: "it seems unnatural" Sure, I'm just proving that that's the issue by unrolling it so that we have explicit types. You didn't ask me to write gorgeous code for you, you asked what the compile error means and what causes it. I told you that. (Anyway, what _you_ are doing is unnatural from the get-go, because an array-of-protocols is not a real type and will soon get you into trouble.)

Comment: Don't get me wrong I appreciate the help. OK, I guess, I can expect more trouble down the road, thanks for the warning.

Comment: I think I will report a swift bug. Btw, I intend to back my array with real objects elsewhere, I stripped my example to the bare bones. Thanks again.